# First boot failing with "Can't find /root in /etc/fstab"

Tags: system-installation

I can't make elementary OS boot after a fresh install. I tried to reinstall it 3 times but always end up with the same error. The only thing I can think of is faulty new SDD which hasn't been tested yet. Google isn't much of a help in this case. 
My laptop is a cheap Chinese ezBook 3 pro, but it worked OK with different SSD and Linux Mint installed.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. In order to boot correctly I had the edit boot parameters in rEFInd. At rEFInd main screen highlight elementary, press F2 and then F2 again. At the end of the line just add "root=/dev/sdX" (without parentheses) where X is your root partition. Now I would like to know why it worked without it in Ubuntu and mint.